# How to create a wii option selector with devkitpro?

Tags: c, homebrew, wii, devkitpro

How to create a wii options selector like wii mod lite? (devkitpro + C) [wii mod lite options selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPmhB.png)

i searched and searched, but i didnt found anything

Comment: Time to go look at some [tutorials](https://wiibrew.org/wiki/Homebrew_development_tutorials)! It may be easier to learn how to use SDL first since they provide a text rendering API which is fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

While SDL is a possiblity as @SafelyFast mentioned you could make something *visually* similar by simply using `printf` along with the ability to clear the screen. You can use the `console_init` function to start the console to use `printf` with and `VIDEO_ClearFrameBuffer` to fill the whole screen with your color of choice.

These are pretty well summed up in a very simple Hello World program [here](https://github.com/devkitPro/wii-examples/blob/master/template/source/template.c). You can also see how controller input is used. The one thing it doesn't cover is `VIDEO_ClearFrameBuffer` but the usage of this command to flood fill the entire screen blank would be `VIDEO_ClearFrameBuffer(rmode, xfb, COLOR_BLACK)` when inserted into that `while(1)` loop.

Overall however I don't know if this factors into what you want to do however, as I'm not sure this would mix to well with libraries like SDL, if that's what you wanted to use instead. I would however suggest getting familiar whit some other examples of wii homebrew as well as they usually cover things like this as well. Sometimes its best to just get your hands dirty...